# contains any of string linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this `linq` query-

Where string `Creative` and `Artistic` would be match.

It is a query of records where particular record contains any of these string matches.

**Query-**

```
Public ActionResult Creative(){

  string[] stringArray = {"Creative","Artistic"};
  var creativelist = (from u in db.CardTables
                      Where u.TagName.Any(stringArray.Contains)
                      select SomeModel{})
                     .ToList();
}
```

I want to select where column `TagName` contains any of these strings or both.

Comment: You haven't got a `where` clause at the moment, and you haven't told us what happens when you try the code you've got. (You haven't actually asked a question at all.) Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and clarify your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Its my mistake.

Comment: Well that code still wouldn't compile, because C# is case-sensitive... and even after fixing that, it's still not clear what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] stringArray ={"Creative","Artistic"};
var creativelist = (from u in db.CardTables
                    where stringArray.Contains(u.TagName))
```

Answer (score 1):

if this has to be done using lambda then i would do like

```
var creativelist = db.CardTable.Where(x=>stringArray.Contains(x.TagName)).ToList()
```

so in your case

```
string[] stringArray ={"Creative","Artistic"};
var creativelist = (from u in db.CardTables
                    where stringArray.Contains(u.TagName))
```